# Pop up menu opens new tab instead of continuing in the same tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have some code where I click on pop up menu button, then menu appears and when I do next .click() on menu element, it tries to open new tab with the AJAX link from the menu option but I want to use it as user would, then it would do the trick in the same tab, without opening new. Is there any way to make browser think that user clicked that?

`HTML`

```
<a class="_54nc" href="/ajax/groups/members/remove.php?group_id=xxx&amp;uid=xxx" rel="dialog-post" role="menuitem">
<span>
<span class="_54nh">Remove from group</span>
</span>
</a>
```

`JS`

```
array = $('a._54nc').get();
array[0].click();
```

So basicly, if user would click that link, the next popup on the same tab would be showed, but when I do this with javascript, it tries to open the AJAX link in new tab witch ends with failure.

Comment: If you have some code, please show the relevant part of it.

Comment: How many times can you get downvoted for nothing, without a word, I guess I did terrible mistakes that can't be even explained to me, cool.

Comment: You just don't give enough information. Why not just post a couple of lines of your javascript and a snippet of HTML in the question? Look at questions that don't get downvoted. Nobody wants to upset you, but nobody wants to do guesswork either.

Comment: Thank you. I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) loaded in the browser's tab, then you can create a [mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) and then trigger the event to replicate the effect of user clicking the dom

```
/**
* create mouse event and dispatch
* param {string} type     event name
* param {DOM Element} el  DOM element on which event will trigger
*/
function triggerMouseEvent (type, el) {
    var myEvent = new MouseEvent(type, {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    });
    el.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
}

var array = $('a._54nc').get();
var element = array[0];
triggerMouseEvent('mousedown', element);
triggerMouseEvent('mouseup', element);
```

---

### Second solution

If you want to open the url in same window, then you can change the location of window. (as pointed out by @some-non-descript-user in the comments)

```
var uri = element.getAttribute('href');
self.location.href = uri;
```

Another thing you can do is to insert the iframe in your page with the same url.

```
var myFrame = '<iframe src='+uri+' width="'+window.innerWidth+'" height="'+window.innerHeight+'" style="position:absolute;"></iframe>';
$('body').append(myFrame);
```

and you can hide the rest of the dom

Comment: This seems like a perfect solution for my problem but it is not working. Even in Chrome console it is saying "Undefinied" and no errors are shown. Or with this code

`function triggerMouseEvent (type, el) {
    var myEvent = new MouseEvent(type, {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    });
    el.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
}

arr = document.getElementsByClassName('_54nc');
element = arr[1];
triggerMouseEvent('mousedown', element);
triggerMouseEvent('mouseup', element);`




It says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined(…)`

Comment: @Lotherad Have you tried to explicitely set the target attribute to `"_self"`?

Comment: @Lotherad Another possibility, though more work, maybe dump `click()` method and just extract the URL from the menu item and use old-fashioned `window.location.href = ...`

Comment: It seems there is no dom element in the `element` variable. have you tried break point or `console.log` to check if you are getting dom element.

Comment: Or another solution could be as @som-non-descript-user pointed out that you can extract the url and open it in a new chrome window.

Comment: @Lotherad I have updated the answer and added the second solution

Comment: But the whole thing is about NOT opening link in new tab because you can't access AJAX of this site on user level. I want to deal with everything on the same tab.

Comment: @Lotherad can you try extracting the url from anchor element and after that, change the location of window. `var element = array[0];` `var uri = element.getAttribute('href');` `self.location.href = uri;`

Comment: So I had little break from the writing and came back now. All you guys doing is trying to open this link in the new tab which is opposite of what I want. This `var element = arr[x]; var uri = element.getAttribute('href'); self.location.href = uri;` also opens link in new tab...